# Creating CloudKit subscriptions in production environment

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, cloudkit, subscription

I'm trying to create a CKSubscription with a custom predicate that matches the current user ID. It works perfectly when running in development but when switch to production the following error occurs:

```
error saving subscription: "Error saving record subscription with id 303D72C8-A43F-4F18-8A2A-D0D9FEB0D65E to server: Cannot create or modify field \'notif_alert\' in record \'_sub_trigger_sub_51FF1A188EF28BF4241E95152E18E1FD\' in production schema
```

Obviously as the the predicate is unique to the user, I can't just deploy the CKSubscription from development to production. Does anyone know how to create a subscription in production with unique predicates (due to unique user id's) for each user? The code for implementing the subscripiton is below:

```
//Setting up profile like notifications, triggered from CloudKit
    let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "ProfileLikes", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "toUser == %@", currentUser), options: .firesOnRecordCreation)

        let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
    info.alertBody = "You've got a new profile like. Open up to find out who ️"
    info.shouldBadge = true
    info.soundName = "default"

    subscription.notificationInfo = info
    CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.save(subscription, completionHandler: { subscription, error in
        if error == nil {
            // Subscription saved successfully
            print("subscription successful")
        } else {
            print("error saving subscription: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
```

Comment: I have used `CKQuerySubscription` once.  There is no such a thing as a flip switch when you switch from development to production to my knowledge.  You simply misunderstand how it works.

Comment: @ElTomato thanks, do you know why my code works in development scheme but not in production scheme?

Comment: No, I don't.  I don't know a guy named 'currentUser', either.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why yours is not working.  But the answer to your question of "how to create a subscription in production with unique predicates (due to unique user id's)" is that the parameters in a query predicate can be specific to the user and still be in the same CKSubscription deployed to Production.  In particular:

```
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UserID" = %@",currentUser];
```

should work fine.